# relationship between the point m and line in projective space

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

a 3-vector [a b c]T can be either a point in projective space of dimension 2(p2) or a line in P2. What is the relationship between the point m ~ [a b c]T and the line l ~ [a b c]T ?(explain) (Hint: find the distances from the origin to both m and l )

Comment: Welcome to MSE! In order to have more chances of getting a satisfactory answer you should follow some basic rules that you can find [HERE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange). Some of them are: 1 use MathJ and 2 show tour personal effort.

Comment: To elaborate on what Dog_69 said, please 1) [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2913328/edit) your question to use [MathJax formatting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/35416) for all the formulas (as in `$m\sim[a\;b\;c]^T$` for $m\sim[a\;b\;c]^T$) and 2) in that edit also tell us what you have tried, in particular with respect to that hint. Have you got a formula for the distance in either case? If so, what does it simplify to, how does it compare, and what does that tell you? If not, where exactly did you get stuck?